# Why is my AppFunc called twice for each owin request?

Tags: owin

I have this simple self hosted "Hello World" app which I doesn't understand how it works 100 %.

```
namespace HelloOwin
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
    using Owin;
    using AppFunc = System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: "http://localhost:9765/"))
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                var task = context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world!");
                return task;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

For each request I'm doing to this application the `Func` defined in `app.Run` is run twice, why so?

Comment: are you doing the request using a browser. Sometimes I see browsers send a second request to fav.ico file which might be the reason why your appfunc is invoked twice. To know the exact reason try printing the request path for each request in your app.Run(). For example you can do that by printing context.Request.Path.Value.

Comment: That sounds like the cause of it. I'll check it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Preinitialization calls means just some code that you want to be executed before you call configureapp in the startup. you can do some operation that requires this or some logging really depends on your requirements.